# Expressions for Permanent of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

Given that the permanent of a matrix can be written in a similar form as the determinant, as a sum of permutations of the elements of the matrix, is there also a relationship between the permanent and the eigenvalues of the matrix? Analogous to the determinant given by the product of eigenvalues?
Also, does anyone know of a comprehensive reference on matrix permanents? It's hard to find a good one (maybe it's just because there isn't a lot written on them.)

Comment: Have you looked at any books on Combinatorial Matrix Theory?

Answer (score 9):

There can't really be a simple relationship, because the permanent is **basis-dependent** whilst the eigenvalues are not.

For example, $$\pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1}^{-1} \pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1} \pmatrix{1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1} = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3}$$
transforms from permanent $1+4=5$ to $-3$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will probably not find any nice relations like that. Unlike the determinant, the permanent does not satisfy the usual nice identities, like the multiplicative property, Perm (A B) $ \neq $ Perm(A) Perm(B), or cyclic identity of Trace, so probably the permanent is not preserved under similarity transformation.

Comment: Apologies for the similar answer, but I'd started typing it up, and the lack of multiplicativity is not sufficient, as you suggest, to guarantee that it is not preserved under similarity transformations. One obvious example is the trace.