# Is the matrix permanent invariant under rotations?

Tags: matrices, permanent

The determinant is, since it's just the product of the eigenvalues.  What about the permanent?

Comment: No. Did you try 2x2 matrices?

Comment: Related [634316](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634316/expressions-for-permanent-of-a-matrix?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expressions for Permanent of a Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634316/expressions-for-permanent-of-a-matrix)

Answer (score 2):

When you say rotations, what do you mean.

Multiply matrix $A$ by a rotation matrix?

$R(\theta) = \pmatrix{\cos \theta &\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta}$

In that case no.

e.g.
let $A= \pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}$

$\text {perm.} A = 2$

$RA =  \pmatrix{\cos\theta - \sin\theta & -\cos\theta + \sin\theta\\-\cos\theta - \sin\theta&\cos\theta + \sin\theta}$

$\text {perm.} RA = 2\cos 2\theta$

But if you mean moving the elements around the matrix like so...

$A = \pmatrix {a&b\\c&d}\\
A' = \pmatrix {b&d\\a&c}$

Then yes, as perm A is invariant under the permutation of rows or columns, and under transposition.  And this transformation is invariant.

Comment: The permanent is invariant under "rotating the matrix" but the determinant is not, so I wonder what the OP is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The permanent is a sum of products for all possible choices of $n$ elements of the matrix in different rows and columns. We get the same products if we rotate the matrix, hence the same permanent.